How can I create a custom app folder for iOS, visible in Files app?
Context
I'm developing a Flutter app for iOS and I want to create a custom folder for my app that's visible in the iOS Files app, similar to how Chrome has its own application folder.
Desired output
For example, the Chrome/Edge apps have their own folder:

My attempt
The following code creates a folder named "MyCustomFolder" in the app's documents directory, but it's not visible in the Files app.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Custom Folder Example')),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Create Folder'),
            onPressed: () async {
              await createCustomFolder();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<void> createCustomFolder() async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final customFolder = Directory('${directory.path}/MyCustomFolder');
  
  if (!await customFolder.exists()) {
    await customFolder.create();
    print('Custom folder created at: ${customFolder.path}');
  } else {
    print('Custom folder already exists at: ${customFolder.path}');
  }
}

Question

How can I make the folder (named "MyCustomFolder" here) visible and accessible like Chrome's folder in the IOS Files app?


On iOS, each app gets its own sandboxed directory automatically when it's installed.
This directory is created by the iOS system, not by your app itself. It's where the app can store its data.
To create a custom folder for your iOS app that's visible in the Files app, you need to do two things:

Create the folder within your app's sandbox (which you're already doing).
Enable file sharing for your app.

Step 1:
First off all, you can keep your createCustomFolder() function as is. Since It's correctly creating a folder in your app's sandbox.
Step 2:
To make your app's documents folder (and subfolders...) visible in the Files app, you need to add keys to your Info.plist file.
Open your project directory, and find the Info.plist file, and add these keys:
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>

Explanation:

UIFileSharingEnabled:
Makes your app's files visible in the iOS Files app.

LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace:
Allows the app to open and modify files directly in their original location, rather than making a copy of the file to work with.


After running adding the correct keys, (and you ran your code) you should see a "MyCustomFolder" folder the Files app under your app's name.
